# Get the pointer of a Java ByteBuffer though JNI

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

How can I get a pointer to the inner array of a Java ByteBuffer?

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiso) {
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/nio/ByteBuffer");
    jmethodID aloc = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "allocateDirect", "(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;");
    jobject obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, aloc, 1000);
}
```

PS: I'm doing that to share the memory used by Java and C++.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? If you need to return 2 things then return a struct.

Comment: Does `m_buffer` already point to allocated memory? If so, why do you say `new`?

Comment: After some research, I rewrote, and now it's much simplier

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
void * data = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(obj);
```

The ByteBuffer must be a direct one for this to work.

Comment: I think `Byte* data = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(obj);` would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return the address of the first element within `m_buffer`, then you can just do:

`return m_buffer;`

..or:

`return &m_buffer[0]`